# Glyph origins of '進'

Tags: characters, etymology, glyph-origin

## Motivation

While writing [my recent meta question](https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/21386), I've cited [Dr. Gavin Chiu (趙善軒)'s article](http://linuxyeo.pixnet.net/blog/post/288479369-%E7%B0%A1%E9%AB%94%E5%AD%97%E8%88%87%E5%8E%BB%E4%B8%AD%E5%9C%8B%E5%8C%96---%E8%B6%99%E5%96%84%E8%BB%92%3B-%E6%97%A5%E8%AA%9E%E4%B8%AD%E8%88%87%E6%BC%A2%E8%AA%9E%E7%94%A8) to explain the character '進' and its simplified character '井'.  However, a user points out that the linked article is not real academic material, and that such explanation is invalid.

## Question

How do the glyphs '⻌' and '隹' come up together to bring the meaning of '進'?

## My attempt

The bone script (甲骨文) for '進' reads [image: 進甲骨文].

In [*Shuowen Jiezi* (說文解字)](http://ccamc.co/cjkv.php?cjkv=%E9%80%B2), there's simply a one-line explanation.

> 登也。从辵。閵省聲。

It's not hard to identify the left glyph in the ancient writing [image: 說文解字] in 說文解字 as '辵', but I can't understand the role of '登' in 說文解字's explanation for '進'.  The right glyph '隹' clearly represents a bird [image].

Source of images for ancient scripts: [*The Complete Collection of Ancient and Modern Characters* (古今文字集成)](http://ccamc.co/index.php)

Comment: 登 means to _ascend/mount_ in Chinese. Its connection to _bird_ and _motion_ stands to reason.

Comment: The 登 there is just to say that it has (had) the same meaning of 進 back then. Not all characters are meaning-based, many of them are sound-based, and that's what the Shuowen is trying to tell you: from an abbreviation of 閵 (lin), that is, take the 門 off, you get 隹 as a sound component. But either way, Shuowen is not made under scientific criteria at all, and you should not trust it. And I don't have time right now to look any further, and probably droooze will come soon and give you the right explanation. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image: ⿱隹止]
[京津](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)4001
[合集32535](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=32535&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>[隸定](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B6%E5%AE%9A)
[image: ⿱隹止]</kbd>

「進」 was originally constructed from semantic [「隹」 (*picture*](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=1101) *of a bird*) and semantic [「止」 (*picture*](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=141) *of a foot* > *motion*), indicating the *flying motion of a bird*, which infers the meaning *forward, advance* (**birds cannot fly backwards**). Later on, 「彳」 (left half of [「行」, *picture*](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=447) *of a road intersection* > *roads, movement, path*) was added to form the equivalent semantic component 「辵・⻍」 (*walking, motion*).

<kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image: 進]
圜器
[集成10360](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=10360&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)・[帛](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_Silk_Manuscript)
[image: 進]
[帛乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)8.5
長沙子彈庫</kbd><kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_han)
[隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
[image: 進]
白石神君碑</kbd>
　
<kbd>[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image: 進]</kbd>

---

Note, 「辵」 is the full form of 「⻍」. As stated earlier, 「辵」 is made up from a merger between 「彳」 and 「止」, shown again via 「過」 below.

<kbd>西周
金
[image: 過]
過伯簋
[集成3907](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=3907&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>戰國・楚
簡・帛
[image: 過]
[語叢3](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)
 [郭店楚簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guodian_Chu_Slips)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
簡
[image: 過]
[效律](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/QinwenziReference)9
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>東漢
隸
[image: 過]
華山廟碑</kbd>
　
<kbd>楷
[image: 過]</kbd>

---

**References:**

- 何琳儀《戰國古文字典：戰國文字聲系》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Comment: Non-linguistic nitpick: The birds _found in China_ cannot fly backwards; [hummingbirds on the other hand](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/80beats/2012/09/28/watch-this-hummingbirds-fly-forwards-and-backwards-with-equal-ease/)...

Comment: @Michaelyus yes, but that is a side-effect of them being able to *hover* rather than fly in general :) Hummingbirds are unique in that respect.