# Glyph origin of 邊/边

Tags: glyph-origin, character-components

What's the story behind this character 邊? This seems to be another "phonetic-semantic" explanation on this character with 辵 as the semantic and 臱 as the phonetic.
But what exactly is 臱? I have never seen this character in any other character besides 邊. Nose 自, hole 穴, and square 方 doesn't seem to make sense to me if I were to break the components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

| 時期 字體 | 字形 | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty) [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script) | [image: ⿱自丙] | [後](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2.22.16 [合集28058](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=28058&jgwfl=) |
| [西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou) [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions) | [image: ⿰彳臱] | [大盂鼎](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da_Yu_ding) [集成2837](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2837&jgwfl=) |
| 西周 金 | [image: 邊] | 散氏盤 [集成10176](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=10176&jgwfl=) |
| [戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_(state)) 石刻文 | [image: 邊] | 詛楚文 |
| [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) | [image: 邊] |  |

「邊」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*pˤe[n]/**, *borders* [e.g. of a political territory or geographical region]) was originally constructed from semantic [「自」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=436) (*from, beginning of* [a location]) and phonetic [「丙」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=157) (**/*praŋʔ/**). To clarify, 「自」 (*from*) is used to indicate that *A political territory starts **from** its **borders***.

> 「自」 indeed was originally a picture of a *nose*. However, very early on, it was used for a word meaning *from* [a location], e.g. [《甲骨文合集》24228](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=24228&jgwfl=):
>
> > [image: 《甲骨文合集》24228]
> >
> > 辛酉卜，尹鼎（貞）：＂王步**自**商，亡（無）（災）？＂
> >
> > [Divination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone#Shang_divination) on the day of [*xīnyǒu*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%BE%9B%E9%85%89), [Oracle Yǐn](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E8%B4%9E%E4%BA%BA) asked: "The King is to set off **from** [Shāng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty) territory. This won't be disastrous, right?"

Later on, 「彳」 (*roads*) and/or 「辵・辶」 (*movement along roads*) was added.

> Note that, in older characters, 「彳」, 「止」, and 「辵・辶」 are often interchangeable as semantic components. See e.g. [Glyph origins of '進'](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/34264/glyph-origins-of-%E9%80%B2).

「方」 (**/*paŋ/**, *direction, side* > [*neighbouring state* 方國](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E6%96%B9%E5%9B%BD)) was also either added to the character or replaces 「丙」 as another phonetic component, and perhaps also acts as a semantic component.

> 「方」 was very early on used to denote neighbouring states to Shāng, e.g. from [《甲骨文合集》6409](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=6409&jgwfl=):
>
> [image: 《甲骨文合集》6409]
>
> > 丁酉卜，㱿鼎（貞）：＂今⿱屮口（早）王廾（供）人五千正（征）土方，⿳爫舟又（受）㞢（有）又（祐）?＂
> >
> > Divination on the day of *dīngyǒu*, Oracle Què asked: “This morning, the King gathered five thousand people to go on a military expedition towards the State of Tǔ; will they receive Divine Protection?”

---

Note that 「穴」 is an attempt to capture the shape of 「丙」; there is no functional 「穴」 in the character.

---

**References:**

- 杜忠誥《說文篆文訛形釋例》
- 何琳儀《戰國古文字典：戰國文字聲系》
- [漢語多功能字庫](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/)
- [小學堂字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)